# Struggling to pass request.user.id to SQL function in python/django

Tags: python, django, authentication, request

hoping someone can help as I'm new django (and coding) and I'm stuck with trying to pass the current user's ID number to an SQL function. I've spent days searching for a solution but nothing I've tried has worked. I know the SQL function works as I can pass through a number without any issue, but when trying to use request.user it just comes up blank.

views.py:

```
def my_custom_sql(request):
    current_user = User.objects.get(request.user)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT first_name FROM customuser WHERE id = %s",[current_user])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'my_custom_sql': my_custom_sql})
```

models.py:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    # add additional fields in here
    employee_dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_executive = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

dashboard.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> <br>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

<p>Is this the your first name?: {{my_custom_sql}}</p>

{% else %}
    <p>You are not logged in, please do so.</p>

{% endif %}
```

I've read everything I can find around the issue but haven't found anything yet that has helped. I'm not sure if it has something to do with sessions or django hashing the info? But I'm not sure how to get around this safely. 
Anyone got any idea how to resolve this so that the logged in user's id number (pk) is passed to current_user for this to work? There's no error code for me to work around, it just returns a blank output where the user's first name should appear. Really trying to learn here so explanations of where I've gone wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't do *any* of this. Why are you using raw SQL? Why do you have both User and CustomUser models? Which one is the AUTH_USER_MODEL? Why are you taking `request.user`, which is presumably already a User, and using it to query User again? Why are you passing that user object, rather than the ID, to the raw query? Just don't. Basically, `request.user` should *already be* the instance of CustomUser you want, and you don't need to do anything at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me but as I said I'm completely new to this. I'm only using raw SQL to test this, but will be using a stored procedure. I thought CustomUser and User were essentially the same thing here, didn't think I was using them both? I just want to pass the user id so how do I do that? I've read other comments that directed me towards doing the above but I'm a total amateur so I can't really answer the questions you've raised because I don't know myself.

Comment: K-15, I think you should review some of Django's tutorials and documentation to better understand how to best build a Django application. The ORM is a huge part of Django and in your comment you state that you want to use raw sql and stored procedures. If that's a hard requirement for you, then you should use a different web framework. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/

Comment: I've been asked to use stored procedures as a university requirement, is there no way to fix the above or can someone actually explain what to do? I was following the "Executing custom SQL directly¶" section here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let anyone know that has this issue that the reason it didn't like was only because the user.id is an integer and the SQL query was expecting a string. So by converting it to string using the str() command, it worked as below.

However, this would open the app to SQL injection attacks as it's raw SQL so the below is fine for proof of concept projects or testing but isn't suitable for production level (more info here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection?fbclid=IwAR3v5wwb52TfA4CyOTxDZWiuMAqVl4zdjr9hLEW2WwU7ZKhv85jQdKIe5Zs). Instead use stored procedures and parameterisation (I think, again I'm new to this so could be wrong).

```
def my_custom_sql(request):
    current_user = str(request.user.id) #use str before passing argument to convert to string from db
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT first_name FROM customuser WHERE id = %s",[current_user])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

Also request needed to be added into the context for the views:

```
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'my_custom_sql': my_custom_sql (request)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Just need to change the value of 'current_user' variable

def my_custom_sql(request):
    current_user = request.user.id
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT first_name FROM customuser WHERE id = %s",[current_user])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your suggestion. I tried this too but it also doesn't work. I really don't understand why it doesn't work though as I'm fairly sure that it should?